# how to recreate .ovpn file from existing openvpn

Tags: openvpn

I have ".ovpn" file of my dev openvpn which is running in AWS but I want to make this file reconfigured as this file was shared with multiple teams. How can I recreate a new .ovpn file from my existing openvpn??

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you want to reconfigure? To create a new VPN from the existing one, copy the existing one and make changes to the copy.   I wonder if you should be focussing on rolling out PKI (public key infrastructure) and focussing on that side of things.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is create a new `connection profile`. The documentation on how to do this is [here](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/create-connection-profiles-and-connect-client-installers/). The exact command differ depending on the kind of profile you want to generate. For example to create a [user-locked profile](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/create-connection-profiles-and-connect-client-installers/) use these commands:

```
./sacli --user <USER_NAME> AutoGenerateOnBehalfOf
./sacli --user <USER_NAME> GetUserlogin >client.ovpn
```

Consult the documenation for the different kinds of profiles and options you have.